# Invalid request changeset action

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, error, batch, postman

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to convert a POST request (which is working) to a batch but I am encountering this error/response.

```
--batchresponse_f248d33f-065b-43a0-8dd7-d69e63e98579
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
CONTENT-TYPE: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8

{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Invalid request."}}}
--batchresponse_f248d33f-065b-43a0-8dd7-d69e63e98579--
```

Would appreciate any help/hints.

[image: via PostMan]

Answer (score 0):

Use items instead of get items to compare the result:

```
 POST https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('OldList')/items HTTP/1.1
```

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis